# Can We call Jersey Web Service server from a client implemented in restlet framework?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, restlet-2.0

My Web Service have been implemented in Jersey Framework.
I want to call this web service  ( server) from client which I want to implement in restlet framework.
Is it possible ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing stops you from doing that :). Fundamentally, all you do is **invoke a HTTP URL by passing some parameters**. *REST is all about this very basic principal*. So under the hood, all the REST client implementations do this. Please go ahead and use whichever REST client you are comfortable with.